# Es posible la serializacion de subclases creadas por mi?

Tags: java

les comento, tengo lo siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un pequeño error a la hora de serializarlas, marca que no son serializables.
Existe alguna posiblilidad de que se puedan serializar?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible solamente tienes que hacer que las clases/subclases que quieras serializar implementen la interfaz Serializable por ejemplo:

```
public class MiClase implements Serializable
{
}
```

La interfaz serializable no tiene ningun metodo asi que no deberas preocuparte por implementar metodos.

Comment: Gracias Franco, en cuanto eh ido a intentar poner a todo implements Serializable, me eh topado con que tengo clases heredadas de JPanel por ejemplo, y en esas no eh podido, aun así lo intenté y me sigue arrojando el error ese:jul 27, 2018 6:50:14 PM interfaz.Interfaz$3 actionPerformed
GRAVE: null
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)

Comment: Deberias Serializar los datos con los que instancias a tus JPanels y demas asi el que se encarga de crear la "Imagen" que se veria seria el propio programa y no una serializacion del mismo.
Te adjunto un link por si no me explique bien 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262387/how-to-serialize-the-jpanel

Comment: `public class TipoArchivo implements Serializable {

    private String nombreArchivo, nombre, ruta;
    private int tempo, vol, pan;
    private boolean btnSolo, btnMute, rbtnSelected;
    private boolean[] patron;` eh utilizado una clase solo con datos importantes, gracias.